# How much range Oracle Number(18) can store?

Tags: database, oracle, numbers

I was looking at documentation that a number type in oracle db can store range from 10 raise to -130 to 10 raise to 126.

Was wondering how many positive numbers a field NUMBER(18) can store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer numbers with up to 18 digits (Integers between `-10^18+1` and `10^18-1`)

According to [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832), the `NUMBER` datatype stores fixed and floating-point numbers. Optionally, you can also specify a precision (total number of digits) and scale (number of digits to the right of the decimal point):

`NUMBER (precision, scale)`

If no scale is specified, the scale is zero.

In your case, `NUMBER(18)`, you specified a `precision` of 18 digits and did not specify any `scale` so `0` is used (no numbers after the decimal point).